# SharePoint CAML query returning non-existing rows

Tags: sharepoint, caml, csom

I have two regular CAML queries that are returning rows from a SharePoint list that are not visible(within CSOM and JSOM code). It seems that these rows have been deleted, but I am not sure. Why am I seeing row IDs of the rows that do not exist in the list current items.
Am i missing a filter(where statement) that would not allow previously deleted rows do be included.

Please help.

Comment: can you please share your CAML query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you get deleted items from a CAML query.

So, my best guess is that the items you retrieve do actually exist; the *view* you consult in the UI to check manually may be the problem: it may have a filter that excludes the items from the list when you display it...

Or it could be a matter of permissions: the CAML query is maybe executed by a user with more permissions than the one who manaully checks the list in the UI.

One thing to check: go to the "Site content" page and look at the items count for the given list: is it the number you expect?

Comment: This is exactly what the issue was, filter view prevented me from seeing all the items.